# Can you use WASD for movement in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have started playing a new character and the clicking is very intense. I have been thinking that maybe using WASD for movement would make it much easier, instead of having to click to move, click on target, etc.

Is there a way to use WASD in Diablo 3 for movement?

Answer (score 1):

No, at least not from the the game itself.

*Why?*
If you have never played Diablo 2 I suggest you watch a video of some gameplay. The clicking in this game is even "worse" but it is now an expected feature and classic way to play Diablo and Diablo-like (e.g. Path of Exile) games.

*How to play with WASD?*
The only way I know of is to remap these keys to some external script like AutoIt and make it so it clicks in the respective direction when pressing a key.
**This is terrible and I do not recommend it**

*What can I do to reduce the amount of clicking?*
If you have a mouse with more than three buttons and you have an easily reachable button on the side, I recommend to scroll through your key bindings and look for an option called something like 'force walk' and bind it on there. This will make it so you have an extra button for walking, which you can hold down and not automatically attack enemies when moving the mouse over them.

Also holding down buttons on your keyboard or mouse often recasts actions.

Other than that there isn't much I could tell you without seeing you play. Check all the options and try to find out what causes most of the clicking. Maybe there is an option for you.

Comment: You can also hold down the right mouse button to keep moving if you aren't selecting an enemy.

Comment: I don't think that's right. The two main mouse buttons should be fixed to the primary and secondary skill. You will use the skill bound to this slot when holding it down. If you were to use whirlwind on there you would spend all your resources and then start walking. But even then it is different to force walking because hovering over an enemies should trigger a basic attack.

Comment: Sorry, I meant left click.

Comment: Well the same applies. You can put whirlwind on left mouse if I remember correctly.